# how to download libTicore.a framework in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am creating an application in which i want use libTiCore.a Framework.but in the add existing frameworks dialog box their is no framework name libTiCore.a .How  can i get the libTiCore framework in my application.Please anybody help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download libTiCore.a from http://code.google.com/p/iphonical/source/browse/trunk/dev_ti/exampleRuntime/Animals_Project/build/iphone/Resources/?r=364